# Appending the row to data.table works differently than in data.frame: How and why?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, rbind

Why does the following code not work?

```
library(data.table)
team_table <- as.data.table(matrix(NA,ncol = 11))
rbind(team_table,1:11)
```

While the same version with data.frame does?

```
team_table <-as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 11))
rbind(team_table,1:11)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to `list` and it should work

```
rbind(team_table,as.list(1:11))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA
#2:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

It is also the same behavior with `data.frame`

```
rbind(team_table,as.list(1:11))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA
#2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

---

Regarding why it fails, `rbind` in `data.table` is calling `rbindlist` and it is considering the vector (1:11) as a single column.

```
rbind(team_table,1:11)
```

> Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) :    Item 2 has 1
>   columns, inconsistent with item 1 which has 11 columns. To fill
>   missing columns use fill=TRUE.

If we convert it to a `list` with 11 element (`data.frame` or `data.table` are `list` with list elements i.e. columns having same length), it works because it would consider the number of columns to be the same

Answer (score 2):

Since `1:11` is being considered as a column, we can transpose the values to `rbind` it as a row

```
library(data.table)
team_table <- as.data.table(matrix(NA,ncol = 11))
rbind(team_table,t(1:11))

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
#1: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  NA  NA
#2:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11
```

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed try to do something similar but I knew only of transpose() function...